# Extract the HTML code and pase to excel by VBA

Tags: html, vba, onclick

I have this issue need your help.
This is the HTML code:

```html
<img alt="" src="/Content/Images/details.png" 
     onclick="ajxCall4Hotel('20328','01GTKT0/001')">
```

I want to extract the data: "('20328','01GTKT0/001')" and paste it to excel cell by VBA. Any advice for this?

Thank you

Comment: Where does the HTML code reside, in a cell or from external file? And which 'data' do you want from the example code? Given such a simple HTML code, I would think it's just an example. If you have a bunch of HTML code, do they all have the exactly same format?

Comment: If you have that text in a string, use `Instr()` to locate the start and end positions of the part you want, then use Left/Right/Mid to extract it.

Comment: This HTML code is from an external file. All I want is to click on the onclick button "ajxCall4Hotel('20328','01GTKT0/001')", but the number 20328 is variable so i want to extract "20328" first and then add back to my VBA. here my code                      
  Set the_input_elements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("img")
  For Each input_element In the_input_elements
  If input_element.getAttribute("onclick") = "ajxCall4Hotel('20328','01GTKT0/001')" Then
     input_element.Click
    
     Exit For
     End If
   Next input_element